# How to insert a new row into an XLSX file that contains data validations using Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I have been trying to insert a new row into an XLSX file (with Python) using different libraries like openpyxl and win32com, unsuccessfully. My XLSX file contains a couple of cells that are bound to some data validation from another sheet.

For example
[image]

takes on 2 different values, **Ready** or **In Progress** from the worksheet **Validation**

[image]

Whenever I use the openpyxl library I get an error "data validation extension is not supported and it will be removed". When using the win32com library my XLSX file after insertion cannot be opened, example below

```
new_row_data = [['POST ID', 123]]
wb = load_workbook(XLSX_filepath_and_name)
# Select Second Worksheet
ws = wb.worksheets[1]
# Append new Row
for row_data in new_row_data:
    # Append Row Values
    ws.append(row_data)

wb.save(XLSX_filepath_and_name)
```

I thought the process would be an easy one but so far I hit a brick wall. Appreciate your help.